# Удалять элемент в GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Есть ориентировочно фотографии которые добавляю в GridView.

На данный момент их удаляю с помощью следующего метода:

```
                    closeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        imageUploads.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что он удаляет по последней позиции, вне зависимости от того на какой элемент был нажат.

Необходимо удалять элемент по позиции, на которую нажали.
Самое интересное, что в логах он нажатия на позиции определяет корректно.

Comment: что именно не получается? Выполнить каое-то действие по нажатию на элемент, или удалить определенный элемент?

Comment: По нажатию на элемент, чтоб он удалялся.
То есть добавили мы допустим 5 элементов в таблицу, а потом при нажатии на какой то из них, выбранный элемент удаляется.

Comment: это 2 разных проблемы: 1) выполнить действие по нажатию; 2) удалить элемент. Какая именно у вас?

Comment: Ну получается два проблемы
Первую я думаю можно прописать метод onDelete в xml и потом просто присвоить обработчику
А вот как быть со второй не очень представляю. Нашёл много примеров с listView, но не то (

Comment: GridView это на 98% ListView. Отличие состоит в том, что элементы выводятся по-другому. Методы в xml никогда в жизни не прописывайте - если вы что-то поменяете в коде, или в xml, это может привести к большому количеству не оевидных ошибок. Все лиснеры устанавливайте в java-коде.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы выполнить код по клику на элемент, установите у `GridView` `OnItemClickListener`:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //тут действия, которые надо выполнить по клику на элемент.
    }
});
```

Чтобы удалить элемент из `GridView`, нужно удалить его из адаптера (или из источника адаптера), и вызвать у адаптера метод `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Внутри что то подобное?
     liste.remove(position);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


типо так?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, да, примерно так

Comment: вопрос заключался в том как прописать метод remove
вы же отписали метод нажатия на элемент...

Comment: @VadimMorozov, зависит от того, как вы храните фотографии в списке

Comment: можете пояснить?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Да, могу. У вас в адаптере, вероятно, есть список или массив, в которых хранятся данные. Чтобы удалить элемент из `GridView`, нужно удалить из списка или массива, в котором хранятся данные, и сказать адаптеру, что данные обновились (`notifyDataSetChanged`)

Comment: @VadimMorozov, подробнее смогу сказать, как только вы покажете код.

Comment: да - List<Control> controls = new ArrayList<>(); . Вот собственно проблема в самом удалении. Но весь adapter не хочу скидывать, т.к. кода слишком много, возможно уточните какой конкретно кусок кода показать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45568/discussion-between-metalurgus-and-vadim-morozov).